# C# Form Closed Event Freezing Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So I've currently got this timer on my form:

```
private void timer1_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Stop();
    timervalidation = true;
    this.Close();
}
```

Which is currently going for 1h:

```
timer1.Interval = 3600000;
timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);

timer1.Start();
```

In my form Closed I've got the following:

```
private void Quoting_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    if(timervalidation == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You've Been Inactive For More Than 1 Hour");
    }
}
```

So my program freezes when the messagebox gets shown and I'm not able to click in any other opened form on it. If there's another form with the ticker ticking would this not get excecated? Also, is there an alternative to this where it does not freeze the whole program and still enables the user to utilize the other forms?

Comment: Please _always_ add code as **text**, not image.

Comment: When the messagebox shows, you have to confirm it. It will not go away automatically. And your main window is blocked until that happens, because everything runs on the same thread.

Comment: @Fildor That's correct. It's meant to be just an informational message with no further actions.

Comment: Make sense your guys explanation. I'll try making a new thread with a message box see if that solves it. Thank You.

Comment: @Fildor The messagebox has it's own doevents() loop and will not block the thread. The messagebox is modal, which disables the rest of the application. He should create his own messagebox which isn't modal

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Ooops. Yeah, it's been a while with WinForms. Solution would be the same, though.

Comment: I would also strongly recommend moving the messagebox logic from where it is into `timer1_tick`.

Comment: @mjwills If i do that it then the window won't close until the message box is cleared.

Comment: By creating a new threat i was able to solve my issues. Thank You @Fildor for the suggestion.

Comment: `If i do that` Yes - just like your code now. My point is the logic is in the wrong spot.

Comment: @mjwills could you please explain how the logic is wrong? How else would you obtain the same through good code practice? Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I am saying whatever your logic in `Quoting_FormClosed` is - move it into `timer1_tick`. If you don't want to do that, explain to me _why_ you don't want to do that. Why move it there? Since it is simpler - no need for the `timervalidation` field, for example.

Comment: Think i understand where you're coming from. Reason for that is so that the form can close and run other functions from Quoting_FormClosing which are crucial prior to displaying the message. Otherwise, these won't run until the user has cleared the message box.